# How to know what's wrong with my PC (PC Freezes after few hours of usage)

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze, reboot

So my PC starts freezing (and the sound freezes too) after few hours of usage, and then restarts by it self, no BSOD what so ever so i dont know what happen. if there is bsod, i can check the code, but there's not bsod.

I've checked my harddisk health, and its alright.
My PSU is alot higher than what my pc needed. so not because of power.
MY CPU is kinda old though.
I always open my HWMonitor software to keep an eye on the temperature, and everything is normal (under 65 celcius)

[image]
[image]

I dont know what is exactly wrong with my PC, how to check it ? so i can search how to fix / solve it

thanks

[EDIT]
just checked the event viewer like patkim said in the comments, i found there's alot of critical error in the system windows logs, and all of it is kernel-power
task category 63, event ID 41

[image]

Comment: Some suggestions - Next time it happens, when you restart and boot into Windows, immediately go to Event Viewer (Control Panel – Administrative Tools – Event Viewer) and under Windows logs look into Application & System events for any critical errors reported and see if you can make out anything what might have caused it. Does Intel i7 4470 has integrated graphics? I guess so, if so, remove your GTX 1070 and let it run on CPU’s iGPU for a few days and observe again.

Comment: in application, nothing is  critical,. but in the system there's a bunch of critical and all of it is kernel power, i'll update my question

Answer (score 0):

"sound freezes" - you mean it repeats the same small bit over & over, sometimes even so short as to just be a buzz?
That's a sign of GPU crash - which may be caused by overheat or under-power [& it's quite hard to tell which at consumer level]

First make sure the machine is clean & free of dust, next would be replace the thermal paste on the GPU. If it still does it after that, take it to a repair shop, where they can identify whether it is a dying GPU or PSU.

Comment: yes it repeats the same bit over& over, like dtrtdrtdrdtrdtrdtrdtdrtdrtdrdtrdtrd (if it make sense)  I'll check about the dust thing, and overheat, not really because i keep an eye on the temperature

Comment: if its GPU, recently i upgraded my nvidia driver to studio driver, but before that, the crashing already started